# Running function in node's child_process

Tags: node.js

Let's assume that i have function

```
const log = (text) => {
    console.log(text)
    }
```

and i want to run this function in node's child process. How should i do it? I've searched for answer but nowhere found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`child_process.fork()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options):

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.fork(pathToScriptWithFunction);
```

Comment: that's how i thought to do it, but I wondered if there is other way